# Can we find upper bound for loss functions?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, estimation, loss-functions, bounds

Is it easy to find upper bound for loss functions like 0-1 loss and hinge loss ?!. I always find this sentence, which is "hinge loss is an upper bound of 0-1 loss", Can we compute the upper bound of convex loss functions?!. Does convex loss function have upper bound?! if yes how to find it ?!

Thanks

Comment: It is not entirely clear what your question entails. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: I always find this sentence, which is "hinge loss is an upper bound of 0-1 loss". Can we compute the upper bound of convex loss functions?!. Does convex loss function have upper bound?! if yes how to find it ?!

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

One loss function can be an upper bound of another loss function. E.g. $|e|$ is an upper bound of $\sqrt{|e|}$ in the interval $(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)$ but the opposite is the case in the interval $[-1,1]$. At the same time, most of the loss functions are not bound by a constant (as opposed to another function).

Comment: I don't think , all surrogate loss functions are unbounded. How can 0-1 loss become upper bound ?!

Comment: @missRan, in your question, you talk about a bound for 0-1 loss, not that 0-1 loss itself can be a bound. This is an important distinction.

Comment: Actually, hinge loss is tight upper bound of 0-1 loss, but it's not clear how this can happen. Could you please clarify?!.

Comment: @missRan, could you give a reference for the claim?